# rebase -i HEAD~5 lists much more than 5 last commits

Tags: git

Im trying to Reorder my five last commits, so the most recent, moves back 5 places

```
<--older      newer->
A <- B <- C <- D <-E
```

so it looks like

```
E <- A <- B <- C <- D
```

I ran

```
 rebase -i HEAD~5
```

And was taken to VIM with 5 pick statements. I reordered my pick statements, but I think I forgot to save the file. The rebase ran, but did nothing. But now when I try the same rebase command, I get VIM with pick statements for about 30 or so commits from a few days ago. What could be causing this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the output of `git reflog`.  With no other arguments it will show you the history of the HEAD reference, which might shed some light on what happened.

Also `git log --graph --deocrate` might be useful.

Comment: This simply doesn't happen. Even if you do a `git rebase -i HEAD~5` while in a "detached `HEAD`" state, you still get five commits. This question is very tantalizing (everyone wants to know how this happened) and could be a good question if it were edited to include clear repro steps.